# More efficient iCloud sync?

Tags: ios, icloud, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord. Whenever i save, it saves to iCloud, which takes a couple of seconds. Is there a way for me to:

1. Save without saving to iCloud, so I can choose to do that most of the time?
2. Save to iCloud on a background context? I can put just the save method in a background thread, to do this. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Saving to iCloud with Core Data is an either all in or all out kind of deal. You *can* have multiple stores in your app's Core Data stack. However, this means that moving data from one store (an iCloud store, perhaps) to another (local) store could be achieved by using this method:

```
[NSManagedObjectContext assignObject:<obj> toPersistentStore:<store>]
```

This means, you'd first create the object in the context, then tell it to save itself in your local store. Then, when you're read to move it to the cloud, you can use this method, and save again, this time to iCloud.

The rules for saving data to an iCloud Core Data store should be the same as your local stores. There is no different API for iCloud other than to move your Core Data store to a ubiquitous container, which is handled by magical record. That means, save using a background context (Private Queue Context).